# How to use dagger in Android Studio Beta 0.8.1

Tags: android-studio, dagger, annotation-processing

Older version of Android Studio can use this [config](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-idea.html)

But the beta version do not have this config. Where can I enable code generation in the beta version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation config just appeared after few restarts of my android studio..